# How to disable rapid-commit option on DHCPv6 client (systemd-networkd and dhcpcd)

Tags: amazon-ec2, ipv6, amazon-vpc, dhcpv6

I tried IPv6 support in Amazon EC2 VPC. Amazon EC2 VPC uses RA and DHCPv6 for IPv6 addressing.

## Problem

AFAIK, a EC2 instance receives an RA message with **manged** flag, then it sends a DHCPv6 solicit message to ff02::1:2. DHCPv6 server in VPC is expected to respond to solicit massages.

In case of dhclient, everything works well. But in case of systemd-networkd (or dhcpcd), it seems that DHCPv6 server ignores solicit messages (that is, no DHCPv6 advertise message appears in packets captured by tcpdump)

## Environment

- Linux (coreos 1339.0.0, kernel 4.10.1)
- systemd 231
- dhcpcd 6.11.5 (by docker container with host-network and privileged mode)
- dhclient 4.3.5 (by docker container with host-network and privileged mode)

## My suspicion

DHCPv6 solicit messages sent by systemd-networkd and dhcpcd have **rapid-commit** option. On the other hand, those sent by dhclient do not have rapid-commit option. The presence of that 
option is the most notable difference I've found in the solicit messages from dhclient and the others.

## Question

In case of systemd-networkd (or dhcpcd), how to disable rapid-commit option ?
I want to use systemd-networkd for network management.

Comment: If rapid commit is enabled and the server supports it, you won't see an advertise message; the server will skip directly to reply.

Comment: I guess DHCPv6 server in VPC does not support rapid commit. Simply discard solicit messages.

Comment: That's an RFC violation right there.

Comment: Do you mean DHCPv6 server in VPC is not RFC compliant ? (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3315#section-17.2.1) If so, I have to ask amazon to support it. But now, is there any workaround for this problem ?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The behaviour seems to be allowed by RFC, as per link in above comment.